# How to add one UIButton on Row and Section of UITableview in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am working on one project. In Dashboard View Controller I used UITableview. Now I want to display one UIButton on Cell as well as on Section Header please see below image [image]

Image that contain black background and "Products" is a section and below white background is a row. I have add this Button in header view of section. I am able to handle its/button's UIControlEventTouchUpInside event when I click on upper section of UIButton/PLUS that is displaying in section. 
[image]

Now problem is **how to handle this UIButton/PLUS UIControlEventTouchUpInside event that is displaying on Row [image]?**

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: How to do that means how to give clipsToBounds = NO to section?

Comment: that I have already did but not working

Comment: you have to set image in header view

Comment: @Birendra I have already set in header view of section that i have mention in problem

Comment: @iSashok : default value of  `clipsToBounds` for any view oject is `NO`

Answer (score 0):

Call `bringSubviewToFront` twice for that button so that it will come to front for tableView on first call and then will come front of cell after second call.